# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libutils.so" not found

Tags: java, android

I get this crash on android studio, when i'm open the app, right after self updating the APK.

I read this posts :

[Android Studio: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39710497/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-dlopen-failed-library-libsdl2-so-not-found)

[dlopen(“xxxx”) failed: dlopen failed: library “xxxx” not found 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30909922/dlopenxxxx-failed-dlopen-failed-library-xxxx-not-found)

[Android M crash java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32845956/android-m-crash-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-dlopen-failed)

and i tried to download the file and copy it in `libs` directory, but it still didn't work.

Does anyone know a simple solution ?

BTW, I'm using `sqlcipher`, as I understand it can be related.

Comment: did you add the jni libs to the build.gradle?

Comment: @helldawg13 thanks it worked !

Answer (score -1):

After the help from helldawg13, I needed to add manually the libraries :

I created folder in

> ../src/main

called jniLibs and i extracted there the files like [this](https://github.com/commonsguy/sqlcipher-gradle) project.
Next, I found the file libutils.so [here](https://github.com/pfalcon/android-platform-headers/blob/master/android-1.6_r1/lib/libutils.so) and copied that to jniLibs, 
and its working !

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Hi , I am also having the same issue . Can you share how you fixed your issue ?